# Efficient way to normalize a Scipy Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'd like to write a function that normalizes the rows of a large sparse matrix (such that they sum to one).

```
from pylab import *
import scipy.sparse as sp

def normalize(W):
    z = W.sum(0)
    z[z < 1e-6] = 1e-6
    return W / z[None,:]

w = (rand(10,10)<0.1)*rand(10,10)
w = sp.csr_matrix(w)
w = normalize(w)
```

However this gives the following exception:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 325, in __div__
     return self.__truediv__(other)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 230, in  __truediv__
   raise NotImplementedError
```

Are there any reasonably simple solutions? I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475457/iterating-over-scipy-sparse-matrix-by-column), but am still unclear on how to actually do the division.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237954/multiplying-elements-in-a-sparse-array-with-rows-in-matrix as it doesn't matter if its a row by row elementwise multiplication or division. Of course if someone has a better answer, great :)

Comment: I disagree, this is a different problem.  The duplicate you pointed to does element-wise multiplication, whereas this question seems to want to divide each row by a different value (rather than all non-zero elements by the same value).  Aaron McDaid's solution below should work efficiently (and does not require any copying of data).

Comment: AFAICT it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358962/efficiently-row-standardize-a-matrix

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This has been implemented in [scikit-learn sklearn.preprocessing.normalize](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html#sklearn.preprocessing.normalize).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
w_normalized = normalize(w, norm='l1', axis=1)
```

`axis=1` should normalize by rows, `axis=0` to normalize by column. Use the optional argument `copy=False` to modify the matrix in place.

Comment: Note that if you normalize by features (axis=0) then the returned matrix is of type 'csc' even if w was a 'csr'. This may be unpleasant if you counted on it being a 'csr'

Comment: the other thing is that if one has train and test set how does one 'fit' the normalization on train set?

Answer (score 3):

While Aarons answer is correct, I implemented a solution when I wanted to normalize with respect to the maximum of the *absolute* values, which sklearn is not offering. My method uses the nonzero entries and finds them in the csr_matrix.data array to replace values there quickly.

```
def normalize_sparse(csr_matrix):
    nonzero_rows = csr_matrix.nonzero()[0]
    for idx in np.unique(nonzero_rows):
        data_idx = np.where(nonzero_rows==idx)[0]
        abs_max = np.max(np.abs(csr_matrix.data[data_idx]))
        if abs_max != 0:
            csr_matrix.data[data_idx] = 1./abs_max * csr_matrix.data[data_idx]
```

In contrast to sunan's solution, this method does not require any casting of the matrix into dense format (which could raise memory problems) and no matrix multiplications either. I tested the method on a sparse matrix of shape (35'000, 486'000) and it took ~ 18 seconds.

Comment: What is the fill-in ratio of the (35'000, 486'000) matrix you did tests with?

Comment: 1,657,114 entries were non-zero which results in a ratio of ~0.0096% in my case.

Answer (score 2):

here is my solution.

- transpose A
- calculate sum of each col
- format diagonal matrix B with reciprocal of sum
- A*B equals normalization
- transpose C

  ```
  import scipy.sparse as sp
  import numpy as np
  import math

  minf = 0.0001

  A = sp.lil_matrix((5,5))
  b = np.arange(0,5)
  A.setdiag(b[:-1], k=1)
  A.setdiag(b)
  print A.todense()
  A = A.T
  print A.todense()

  sum_of_col = A.sum(0).tolist()
  print sum_of_col
  c = []
  for i in sum_of_col:
      for j in i:
          if math.fabs(j)<minf:
              c.append(0)
          else:
              c.append(1/j)

  print c

  B = sp.lil_matrix((5,5))
  B.setdiag(c)
  print B.todense()

  C = A*B
  print C.todense()
  C = C.T
  print C.todense()
  ```

Comment: I think doing so many transpose operations can be avoided. All we have to do is to scale the rows instead of the columns. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59365444/6286927

Answer (score 1):

I found this as an elegant way of doing it without using inbuilt functions.

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

def normalize(W):
    #Find the row scalars as a Matrix_(n,1)
    rowSumW = sp.csr_matrix(W.sum(axis=1))
    rowSumW.data = 1/rowSumW.data

    #Find the diagonal matrix to scale the rows
    rowSumW = rowSumW.transpose()
    scaling_matrix = sp.diags(rowSumW.toarray()[0])

    return scaling_matrix.dot(W)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without importing sklearn, converting to dense or multiplying matrices and by exploiting the data representation of csr matrices:

```
from scipy.sparse import isspmatrix_csr

def normalize(W):
    """ row normalize scipy sparse csr matrices inplace.
    """
    if not isspmatrix_csr(W):
        raise ValueError('W must be in CSR format.')
    else:
        for i in range(W.shape[0]):
            row_sum = W.data[W.indptr[i]:W.indptr[i+1]].sum()
            if row_sum != 0:
                W.data[W.indptr[i]:W.indptr[i+1]] /= row_sum
```

[Remember](https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/csr_matrix.html) that `W.indices` is the array of column indices,
`W.data` is the array of corresponding nonzero values
and `W.indptr` points to row starts in indices and data.

You can add a `numpy.abs()` when taking the sum if you need the L1 norm or use `numpy.max()` to normalize by the maximum value per row.

Answer (score 0):

My setup: Python 3.8.10, SciPy 1.5.4

Working just with [csr_array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_array.html#scipy.sparse.csr_array) you could nowadays use its `multiply` and `sum` methods and do:

```py
# w : scipy.sparse.csr_array
row_sum = w.sum(axis=1)
row_sum[row_sum == 0] = 1  # to avoid divide by zero
w = w.multiply(1. / row_sum)
```

Comment: As this is quite an old question it might be good to mention your python version, along with any key packages (and they versions)